# d3.geomap Not Working

Tags: html, d3.js, geomap

I have been trying to get the documentation from http://d3-geomap.github.io/ to work but somehow it's not i can't find my mistake. 
Here is my Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="d3-geomap/css/d3.geomap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="d3-geomap/vendor/d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="d3-geomap/js/d3.geomap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

<script>
var map = d3.geomap()
.geofile('d3-geomap/topojson/world/countries.json');

d3.select('#map')
.call(map.draw, map);
</script>
```

My HTML File is in the root folder.

Comment: have you just copied code or download same on your own machine ?

Comment: I copied the code, downloaded the zip file, extracted everything into my folder and changed the src to my path.

Comment: any error in console ?

Comment: No error in console.

Comment: After double checking, I found an error saying: 
SCRIPT5: Access Dednied
Data d3.geomap.dependencies.min.js, Row: 1, Column: 10922

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if anyone else has the same problem as me - I solved it.

The thing is that windows has some security issues and it blocks some type of code. I couldn't find out the real reason but if u want it to work, just host it on a virtual web server (e.g. www.xampp.com) that did the job for me.